# Bootstrap drop down Navigation Menu in WordPress

Tags: dropdown

I am trying to build a Wordpress theme with boostrap.almost every part is complete but the nav menu is giving me some trouble for days. I would like the dropdown to work like boostraps dropdown, but I do not know how to do this.

So I need:

To add the class "dropdown", if a menu-item has child-items.
dropdown-toggle
sticky-top
also i need necessary bootstrap web srcs or download links and local src like this:  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scriptname.js'
Hope someone can help!

when i try https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker , the page looks like:

[image]

Comment: There are plugins that will do this for you. If you want to DIY, you'll need a custom Nav Walker to add your required CSS classes, and download Bootstrap and enqueue all of its resources in a child theme.

Comment: will these plugins  cause slow the website? if i can do it without plugin, it will be better for me so can you tell me the how to? i found some php files and codes but they didnt work fully.

Comment: A plugin won't slow down your website any more than putting the same code into a child theme will, and the added benefit of a plugin is someone else maintains the code and keeps it all up to date for you. But like I said, you can use a Nav Walker (like the one in Nathan's answer) and also enqueue the required CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to extend the [Walker_Nav_Menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) class. This allows you to "walk" through the various states of a navigation menu. One of the first google searches I did for the term `Walker_Nav_Menu` led me to this Github repo with a class already built. [wp-bootstrap-navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php).

Comment: when i try https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker , the page looks like: [link]https://i.ibb.co/Gtkz0md/Acbds-z.png[/link] how can i fix this situation? only one difference that i added is " sticky-top" and when i remove it, the picture doesnt change

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. It looks like you might need some styling? Not sure what I'm looking at.

Comment: while hamburger buton apears - the menu is in default closed position-, also menu content -page links- apears.other than this problem, everythings good but you know i cant use it with its now situation

Comment: Without knowing your HTML, JS and CSS I couldn't say what the problem is. Do you have a live version viewable to public?